# How to hide div after page loads in plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

I've viewed a couple of the posts in here regarding this topic but not quite working for my situation. I'm using Tampermonkey userscript manager. I want to hide a bunch of div's after the page is fully loaded. I've tested the code below on the console of the page and it works.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('promotions-personalized-offers-ui-single-offer')[0].style.display='none';
```

This alert also works with the Tampermonkey userscript manager.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    // code goes below
    alert("hello world");
});
```

However, the following code is not working. Neither the div or the alert is working in this situation.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    // ....
    document.getElementsByClassName('promotions-personalized-offers-ui-single-offer')[0].style.display='none';
    alert("it's working");
});
```

By the way, I'm a newbie to Javascript so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your code currently only hides the first div.

Answer (score 0):

You currently only hide the first (`[0]`) div. You need to iterate over all elements to hide them. 
I'd suggest using [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) because it's easily iterable:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    document.querySelectorAll('promotions-personalized-offers-ui-single-offer')
        .forEach(e => (e.style.display = 'none'));
});
```

---

If you must stick to `getElementsByClassName`, a [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) should do the trick:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    [...document.getElementsByClassName('promotions-personalized-offers-ui-single-offer')]
        .forEach(e => (e.style.display = 'none'));
});
```

Comment: I tried both of these versions and it's still not working.

Comment: I put the code below in the console of the page and it's not working.

document.querySelectorAll('promotions-personalized-offers-ui-single-offer')
        .forEach(e => (e.style.display = 'none'));

Comment: This code below works on the console but not when managed by Tampermonkey.
[...document.getElementsByClassName('promotions-personalized-offers-ui-single-offer')]
        .forEach(e => (e.style.display = 'none'));

Comment: Just out of curiosity, anything that is inside of the window.addEventListener("load", function() will only execute once the page is fully loaded, correct? Well, if I put an alert inside that function, the alert pops up before the page is even fully loaded. Does that means the window.addEventListener("load", function() is not working?

Comment: Okay, looks like it could be something with the https://mint.intuit.com/overview.event website. I use the same code on Facebook site and the alert shows up after the page is fully loaded. However, for the mint.intuit site, the alert shows up first before everything is loaded.

Comment: @2myCharlie try `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){});` instead of `window.addEventListener("load", function(){});`

Comment: I tried: window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        alert("It's loaded!")
    })
and the alert is not popping up in either Facebook or mint.intuit.com site.

Comment: @2myCharlie It's `document`, not `window`

Comment: I tried: document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    alert("It's loading.");
}); but it's not working in either Mint or Facebook. The alert does not popup at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var x = 3 //number of div elements to remove
window.onload = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    var elementid = "div" + i.toString(); //ends up as "div1" or "div3"
    var div = document.getElementById(elementid)
    document.body.remove(div);
}
```

The divs would need to look like this:

```
<div id="div1">Content</div>
<div id="div2">Content</div>
<div id="div3">Content</div>
```

Alternatively, if you're putting the JavaScript code inside a function that's called after the page loads fully, you can just use this:

```js
var x = 3 //number of div elements to remove
function removeDivs() {
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    var elementid = "div" + i.toString(); //ends up as "div1" or "div3"
    var div = document.getElementById(elementid)
    document.body.remove(div);
}
```

Then call the function by using `removeDivs()`.

Comment: This does not work either. If it's inside of the window.addEventListener then it's not working. The code works when I execute it through the console on the page.

Comment: That might be because the `window.onload` function isn't being set until after the page is loaded. Therefore, it wouldn't trigger. See my edit to the answer.

Comment: This is window.onload = function() {
    alert("It's laoded");
} works Facebook but not Mint.intuit.com site. In the Mint site, the alert still shows up before anything loads on the page. That tells me something must be up with the Mint site.

Comment: @2myCharlie The Mint site probably loads some basic code, then requests additional resources from the server <i>after</i> the page has fully technically loaded. Try using `window.setTimeout` instead.

Comment: Okay, seems like you're right. I tried the setTimeout and it does seem to load the alert after the page is loaded. So, what's the best way to resolve this issue? I don't want to specify a number of seconds because I don't know how long it'll take to fully loaded the page each time.

Answer (score 0):

Tampermonkey by default runs when the DOMContentLoaded event is dispatched.  https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_run_at  Based on what you have posted it does not look like you need the event listener at all.  Your script would only need one line.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('promotions-personalized-offers-ui-single-offer')[0].style.display='none';
```